# How to enable drag-erasing of cell color in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a pixel art maker using jQuery in which the user can draw on a grid with a color of his or her choice. To view my full current code/see how it works, check out my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/VQRrgQ).

I would like to add a drag-erase mode (I've already added a feature enabling the user to erase a single cell by double-clicking it). Here's the code I tried (adapted from near-identical code for color-dragging functionality), which doesn't do anything.

```
$('.erase-mode').click(function() {
  function dragErase() {
    // Filters clicks by those in cells. Note: 'mousedown' event is fired when the mouse button is pressed but before it's released, whereas 'click' event is fired after mousedown (click) and mouseup (release) events have completed
    pixelCanvas.on('mousedown', 'td', function() {
      mousedown = true;
    });

    // 'mouseup': when pointer is over element and mouse button has been clicked then released
    $(document).mouseup(function() {
      mousedown = false;
    });

    // 'mouseover' triggered when mouse pointer enters an element
    pixelCanvas.on('mouseover', 'td', function() {
      if (mousedown) {
        // Selector 'this' refers to pixelCanvas
        $(this).css('background-color', '');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I also tried replacing `$(this).css('background-color', '');` with `$(this).css('background-color', null);` to no avail.

Comment: The `dragErase` function is never called.

Comment: Implementing a _flag_-like variable/value that you set when clicking either _Erase_ or _Draw_ could maybe help. Based on that flag, you could first check if you are erasing or drawing, and then actually call `dragErase` or `dragDraw`